# Variable inside jquery call. But jquery function call happens only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a highlighter jquery function defined. Its called this way:

```js
$('#pi').highlightTextarea({
   ranges: [{
   color: '#FFFF00',
   ranges: curKeyArray
   }]
 });
```

`pi` is the name/id of textarea.
`curKeyArray` is a variable which gets updated as user types text in textarea.
Even after calling the same jquery function after `curKeyArrays` is updated, the call just doesnt happen.

Please help. I tried calling it using ajax. Still the call uses old `curKeyArray`. How do I forcefully call the jquery function?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the code for the `highlightTextarea` function?

Comment: and where you have listener on textarea? How you handle user changes? Is your function yours or any download code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to re-run the jquery function each time you have another ranges for your textbox, as this [plug-in doesn't support refresh](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/) after resetting some of the parameters:

> Simply call highlightTextarea plugin on a jQuery object.
>
> ```
> $(/* selector */).highlightTextarea({
>   /* options */
> });
> ```

You can do it [like this](http://bebo.minka.name/k2work/libs.js/jquery/2.1.0/highlightTextarea/), passing the `setOptions` parameter:

> **setOptions**
>   Update highlight options (you cannot change `resizable`
>   value). Returns `false` if handlers are disabled, `true` otherwise.
>
> ```
> $("textarea").highlightTextarea('setOptions', { ...... });
> ```